# Render these <a> sort buttons inside a dropdown menu wrapper component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a dropdown menu wrapper component for my site's mobile view. I need the dropdown for 6 sort buttons which are currently being mapped as  elements. I've tried a variety of strategies, from building dropdowns with CSS, using buttons, etc. Every time I try to render this component's output as children in the dropdown, I either get nothing or [object Object].

This is the code that renders the sort buttons

```
// DatasetSort GraphQL fields
const sortFields = [
  'created',
  'name',
  'uploader',
  'stars',
  'downloads',
  'subscriptions',
]

export const SortField = ({ field, queryVariables, refetch }) => {
  const fieldValue =
    field in queryVariables.orderBy && queryVariables.orderBy[field]
  let icon
  if (fieldValue) {
    if (fieldValue === 'ascending') {
      icon = <i className="fa fa-sort-asc" />
    } else {
      icon = <i className="fa fa-sort-desc" />
    }
  }
  const sortBy = () => {
    const newQueryVariables = { ...queryVariables }
    // Clear existing sorts
    newQueryVariables.orderBy = {}
    // Apply (or toggle) based on previous sort
    newQueryVariables.orderBy[field] =
      queryVariables.orderBy[field] === 'descending'
        ? 'ascending'
        : 'descending'
    refetch(newQueryVariables)
  }
  return (
    <a
      key={field}
      className={fieldValue ? 'btn-sort name active' : 'btn-sort name'}
      onClick={sortBy}>
      <Capitalized>{field}</Capitalized> {icon}
    </a>
  )
}

const DatasetSorter = ({ queryVariables, refetch }) => (
  <>
    {sortFields.map(field => (
      <SortField
        field={field}
        queryVariables={queryVariables}
        refetch={refetch}
        key={field}
      />
    ))}
  </>
)

export default DatasetSorter
```

While on mobile, I conditionally render this dropdown instead of DatasetSorter. I need the buttons from DatasetSorter to render as options in the dropdown, so I passed it in as children:

```
class DropdownWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = { value: 'Sort By' }
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value,
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}>
          {this.props.children}
        </Select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The dropdown is rendered like this, with the sort buttons inside of it:

```
<DropdownWrapper >
    <DatasetSorter refetch={refetch} queryVariables={queryVariables} />
</DropdownWrapper>
```

I've tried wrapping the children in an options tag. I've tried conditionally rendering the sort 'buttons' in DatasetSorter as different types of elements. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here but I can't figure it what.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this one out by conditionally rendering the  elements as

tags, then injecting them into a dropdown configured to accommodate them (li tags, that is).

Dropdown (using styled components)

```
const Dropdown = styled.label`
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    float: right;
    padding: 0 20px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px;
`

const Menu = styled.div`
    display: inline-block;
    background: #007c92;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
`
const List = styled.ul`
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    list-style-type: none;
    z-index: 99999;

    li {
        padding: 10px 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }
`

const Input = styled.input`
    display: none;
    + .dd-menu {
        display: none;
      } 
    :checked + .dd-menu {
    display: block;
    } 

`


class DropdownWrapper extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Dropdown className="dropdown">
                <Menu className="dd-button">
                    Sort By:
                </Menu>
                <Input type="checkbox" className="dd-input" />
                <List className="dd-menu">
                    {this.props.children} 
                </List>       
            </Dropdown>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The conditional sorting:

```
if (!isMobile) {
    return (
      <a
        key={field}
        className={fieldValue ? 'btn-sort name active' : 'btn-sort name'}
        onClick={sortBy}>
        <Capitalized>{field}</Capitalized> {icon}
      </a>
    )
  } else if (isMobile) {
    return (
        <li
        key={field}
        className={fieldValue ? 'btn-sort name active' : 'btn-sort name'}
        onClick={sortBy}>
        <Capitalized>{field}</Capitalized> {icon}
        </li>
    )
  }
}
```